# How to show the solution to Liouville's Equation

Tags: complex-analysis

One definition of Liouville's equation is $\Delta u + \lambda e^u = 0$. The solution given in Henrici (p. 294) is:

$$ u(z) = \mathrm{log}\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{\Big[1+\frac{\lambda}{8}|f(z)|^2\Big]^2}  $$

Considering that:

$$ \Delta u = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}} $$

I don't understand how the given solution can solve Liouville's equation when $\Delta u$ must contain at least one term with a second derivative of $f(z)$ but there are no terms with a second derivative in $e^u$. Do the second derivative terms somehow cancel or equate to zero?

Comment: Consider using **the Wirtinger Calculus** (See Henrici, Applied and Computational Complex Analysis).

Comment: Actually I figured it out! You do get second derivative terms in $\Delta u$ but they all end up being zero due to the Cauchy Riemann equation $\partial f$ / $\partial \bar{z}$ = 0